# c# - Understanding MouseEvent

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have some doubts regarding some Mouse Event. The ones I am talking about is Mouse_Click Event , PreviewMouse_Down event and MouseDown event. I have read the explanations about these events in MSDN and yet I am having a hard time differentiating these 3.

So far from what I know:

```
Click : Occurs when the control is clicked by the mouse.
Preview: Occurs when any mouse button is pressed while the pointer is over this element.
Mousedown: Occurs when the mouse pointer is over the control and a mouse button is pressed.
```

For example, I don't know which event is suitable for which.Based on the explanations, they seem pretty much the same to me.On top of that, we have PreviewMouseDown which occurs when left mouse button is pressed.Aren't they all the same? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aren't they all the same?

Short answer is "They are all different but depending on the use case, they may serve the same function."

> Can anyone shed some light on this?

So how are they different?

First, let's look at what base classes the events are defined from.

`MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` are from `System.Windows.UIElement`
`Click` is from `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase`.

`UIElement` is a higher abstraction than `ButtonBase` which means that more classes are derived from it. In other words more classes will have the `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` events but not the `Click` event

Also, note that the `ButtonBase` itself derives from `UIElement` thus `ButtonBase` also has the `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` events.

But as stated in documentation of [`ButtonBase.Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Remarks):

> The `ButtonBase` marks the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event as handled in the `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` method and raises the Click event. Hence, the `OnMouseLeftButtonDown` event will never occur for a control that inherits from `ButtonBase`.

Which brings us to the second point, how/when exactly are the events fired on a `ButtonBase`?

Please note that the following explanation considers only the three events (`PreviewMouseDown`, `MouseDown`, and `Click`). Other events may be involved before/between/after the said three events but are disregarded for discussion purposes.

`PreviewMouseDown` will always be the first to fire as soon as whichever mouse button (left or right) is pressed down.

`MouseDown` will occur next when using **right click**.

`Click` will occur next when using **left click** if and only if the mouse left button was also released on the `ButtonBase`

To add, when `ButtonBase` is in focus and the user presses ENTER or the SPACEBAR, `Click` will fire but not `PreviewMouseDown`

There's a whole new discussion on the difference between `MouseDown` and `PreviewMouseDown` events (basically XXX event and PreviewXXX event). You might want to read the documentation for [Routed Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/routed-events-overview) to get you going on that topic.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So, if i have a button and wish to have a button effect, which one should i use?  I tried using MouseDown event and the effect doesn't work but when I tried PreviewMousedown or Click event, the effect works. I am confused.

Comment: I'm not sure what button effect you're looking for but I would think the ButtonBase class or one of its derived classes/controls (Button, ToggleButton, etc) already implements it. No need t reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I tried using Mouse event on a button implemented via XAML, it's not generating the effect I want. Strange

Comment: Still, I don't know the "effect" you're talking about. I think it would be better to just post another question and include your code. Also try to be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Well when I clicked on a button, it should generate a "sunken effect" by increasing the border thickness , I am just not sure which event handler I should use to generate it. I tried using MouseDown but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is related with Event Tunneling and Bubbling.

There is an order of events.

Let's suppose you have a button.
If you left click the button then you would get below **events in turn**.

1) Preview Mouse Left Button Down

2) Preview Mouse Down

3) Mouse Left Button Down

4) Mouse Down

5) Preview Mouse Left Button Up

6) Preview Mouse Up

7) Mouse Left Button Up

8) Mouse Up

For more detail, please refer to Event Tunneling and Bubbling deeply.
http://csharphelper.com/blog/2015/03/understand-event-bubbling-and-tunneling-in-wpf-and-c/